# COLLADA textures not appearing in Scene Kit

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, collada

I'm trying to view a file called test.dae using Scene Kit. When I click on the file in the editor, the object preview in the editor window is modeled properly, including texture. However, when I create a scene with test.dae, the model shows up, but without texture.

Here's my code:

```
var scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/test.dae")
    mySCNView.scene = scene
    mySCNView.allowsCameraControl = true
    mySCNView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true;
    mySCNView.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
```

I can't figure out why the texture would load in the preview, but not in the actual SCNView. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. When exporting from .obj to .dae in MeshLab, checking the Color and Normal options did the trick.